# Rewrite the image markup from specific image field

Tags: 7, theming, media

In a Drupal 7 site, I have an image field that allows unlimited images, called `field_gallery_images`. I built a template file for this field to create a custom image slider. I want to rewrite the HTML markup for the image to add a lazy-load component. So, instead of:

```html
<img src="/sites/default/files/myimage.jpg" width="668" height="500">
```

I want:

```html
<img data-lazy="/sites/default/files/myimage.jpg" width="668" height="500" class="lazyload">
```

Right now, the images are being run through theme_image() and so by the time it gets to the template, the markup is all set. I only want to alter the markup for this one field. I tried theme_preprocess_image(), but that altered all images.

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: Edited. Yes Drupal 7

Comment: Here is the same question for D8: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272250/rewrite-the-image-markup-from-specific-image-field-in-drupal-8 Just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using Drupal 7.

## Short Answer

Implements `template_preprocess_field()` and overrides `theme_image()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];

  if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_image') {
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
      $item = &$element[$key]['#item'];

      $src = file_create_url($item['uri']);
      unset($item['uri']);
      $item['attributes']['data-lazy'] = $src;
      $item['attributes']['class'] = array('lazyload');

      $element['#items'][$key] = $item;
      $variables['items'][$key]['#item'] = $item;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Overrides theme_image().
 */
function mytheme_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

  if (!empty($variables['path']) || !isset($attributes['data-lazy')) {
    $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
  }

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

---

## Long Answer

By implementing [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x), you can alter the **theme variables** and also the **theme function** for a field.

Example code:

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];

  if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_image') {
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
      $item = &$element[$key]['#item'];

      $src = file_create_url($item['uri']);
      unset($item['uri']);
      $item['attributes']['data-lazy'] = $src;
      $item['attributes']['class'] = array('lazyload');

      $element['#items'][$key] = $item;
      $variables['items'][$key]['#item'] = $item;
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to change `field_image` to the field name you defined.

It is the structure of `$variables`:

[image: Structure of $variables]

`$variables['items'][0]['#item']` is a typical usage of theme function in render array. The code above has done a couple of things:

- unset `uri`, which is used to format the attribute `src` in `theme_image()`
- construct image path and assign it to the attribute `data-lazy`
- add `lazyload` to class
- synchronise the item array to different location of `$variable`

The last point is a bit weird, but there are 3 different location always store the same item array. They are

- `$variables['element'][0]['#item']`
- `$variables['element']['#items'][0]`
- `$variables['items'][0]['#item']`

Theoretically, `$variables['items'][0]['#item']` is the only one be used in theme function, But, in my opinion, it is better to change them at the same time for preventing any potential issue in future. **(Maybe someone can provide more suggestion here?)**

The last but not the least, you have to override the `theme_image()`. It is a global change but won't affect too much.

```php
/**
 * Overrides theme_image().
 */
function mytheme_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

  if (!empty($variables['path']) || !isset($attributes['data-lazy')) {
    $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
  }

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

Comment: Jimmy Ko, this is awesome. Thanks for such an in-depth response. Worked perfectly.

Comment: One more question: any thoughts on how I could alter the image src to be a placeholder? I tried adding `$item['uri'] = '/' . path_to_theme() . '/images/placeholder.jpg';` The current image src is `src="//localhost:3010/sites/default/files/styles/property_slideshow_500h/public?itok=zKlJQsDU"` which is essentially no image or a broken image.

Comment: Do you mean a default image for the field? You can upload one in the field settings. If you need more details, please update this question or just raise a new question. I will follow up.